# SQLAlchemy inter table constraint

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to model the case where a system has User, Company, Group and Role models. Where the relationship is as follows.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Unicode(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id'))

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(200), unique=True, nullable=False)

    users = relationship("User", backref="company")
    groups = relationship("Group", backref="company")

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(60), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id'), nullable=False)
    roles = relationship("Role", backref="group")

class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(60), nullable=False)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
```

My issue is that I'm not sure how I can enforce the constraint that users cannot be members of Group or Role without being a member of the company which owns the Group.

Comment: Is your sample code missing the part of the model where `Users` are linked to `Groups`?

Comment: Yes. I wasn't sure the best method to do this, so I left it out. I'm assuming that adding a users = relationship("User", backref="group|role") to both Group and Role is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) To answer the question in the comment:**
Taking your model as a starting point, I would simply add a `M-N` relationship between Users and Roles in order to complete the relationship model:

```
class UserRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'), nullable=False)

class User(Base):
    # ...
    roles = relationship("Role", secondary=UserRole.__table__, backref="users")
```

**2) To answer the constraint question:**

Simple answer: on the database level with the current model you cannot enforce it (I do not know a RDBMS which provides tools for cross-table constraints other than simple FKs). However, with some redundant data you could do it:

1. store also `company_id` in the `Role` table; add composite FK pointing to `Group`
2. store also `group_id` and `company_id` in the `user_role` table, and add composite FK to the `Role`, *which basically is responsible for exactly what you are asking*

The modified code:

```
class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(60), nullable=False)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id'), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([company_id, group_id], [Group.company_id, Group.id]), {})

class UserRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id'), nullable=False)
    role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([company_id, group_id, role_id], [Role.company_id, Role.group_id, Role.id]), )
```

But this is not enough, a you have to modify some more code, because with several FKs between different tables you will need to configure relationship explicitly. Also you will want to add some code (potentially using ORM Events) to add the parent of the parent automatically, etc.

**3) Solution?**

You can definitely use SA [Attribute Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html#attribute-events) to validate your model:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
def append_user_role(target, value, initiator):
    assert target.company, "Cannot validate until the company is set"
    assert target.company == value.group.company#, "Cannot add person %s (from company %s) to a Role %s (from company %s)" % (target, target.company, value, value.group.company)
event.listen(User.roles, 'append', append_user_role)
```

I would probably combine point **3)** with some database views which return all `user_role` rows which are invalid in order to clean those up shall those be inserted not via SA, but via some other means (data import scripts, etc)

Comment: Thanks for that. Events seem to be the best method to solve this issue. I have used @validates('users') on both Group and Role to ascertain that the constraints have been met before adding the user to the Group/Role, and I use an event on 'remove' to cleanup Groups/Roles when a users company or group changes. Although I now have to ensure that any external applications also hold true these conditions.

Comment: This sounds like a really good solution. And validating changes performed outside of the system is always somewhat of a challenge.